# Brackets after function calling brackets in Python

Tags: python, keras

I'm not very familiar with Python, I'm a C/C++ programmer. Recently I have been working with Keras, and noticed expressions such as:

```
X = BatchNormalization(axis=3, name=bn_name_base + '2a')(X)
added = keras.layers.Add()([x1, x2])  # equivalent to added = keras.layers.add([x1, x2])
```

What do those "brackets after function calling brackets" mean in Python?

Comment: `BatchNormalization` is a class that has a `__call__` method, this make all it's instances callable. In your code an instance is created and called with argument `X`.